# Set applicationName configuration

Tags: java, google-sites

I want to connect to Google Sites API using Java code:

```
SitesService client = new SitesService("yourCo-yourAppName-v1<NOT KNOWN WHAT TO SET HERE>");
        client.setUserCredentials("<MY GMAIL ACCOUNT -EMAIL>", "MY GMAIL ACCOUNT -PASSWORD");

        SiteFeed siteFeed = client.getFeed(new URL("https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site/"), SiteFeed.class);
        for (SiteEntry entry : siteFeed.getEntries()){
            System.out.println("title: " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
            System.out.println("site name: " + entry.getSiteName().getValue());
            System.out.println("theme: " + entry.getTheme().getValue());
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

According to the doc: `The applicationName argument should follow the format: company-applicationname-version. This parameter is used for logging purposes.`  I need to set `company-applicationname` but I don't have a company name configured and application name.

Can you guide me?

Ref: https://developers.google.com/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_java

Comment: I don't understand the question. The prototype is `SitesService(java.lang.String applicationName)` You are supposed to to set it to the string `"company-applicationname-version"`. Just make something up that identifies your application.

Answer (score 1):

Its a string filed. You have add anything that you like. You should add company name+application name+version info to identify its your unique application but if you don't have anything and can just add any name that will uniquely identify your application.

My suggestion will be your {email name}{app name}v{number}.